# [MoveIt!] Save a calculated motion plan

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I wanted to know if there is any easy way of saving a plan object to disk or write it as a string.

E.g. you calculated a motion plan for your robot and the next time you load the simulation the same plan should be used for execution.

Couldn't find anything about that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245022/%5Bmoveit!%5D-save-a-calculated-motion-plan/) by [F4bich](https://answers.ros.org/users/27705/f4bich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi F4bich,

There is no standard way to write a motion plan to disk, but it is relatively easy to do using rosbags. Using the rosbag API ([found here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)), it is very easy to store and read from disk.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1